# Converting Blob WebM to audio file (WAV or MP3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I looked through most of the questions here and on google, I couldn't find an easy way to convert webm to wav or mp3. I am aware of lamejs and ffmpeg but it's a bit confusing since it's not primarly designed for react.

I have created a sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/embed/strange-hofstadter-lmcnv?fontsize=14

I tried creating a new file like so but I believe browsers cannot convert the file natively..

```
let newBlob = new Blob(recordedBlob, {type:'audio/mpeg-3'});
```

If someone can assist that would really be great.

Answer (score 1):

First, install the FFmpeg.js library using npm by running the following command in your Angular 6 project directory:

```
npm install @ffmpeg/ffmpeg
```

Next, import the FFmpeg library and define a function that takes a WebM blob as input and converts it to an MP3 blob using FFmpeg.js:

```
import * as FFmpeg from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

async function convertWebmToMp3(webmBlob: Blob): Promise<Blob> {
  const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: false });
  await ffmpeg.load();

  const inputName = 'input.webm';
  const outputName = 'output.mp3';

  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', inputName, await fetch(webmBlob).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer()));

  await ffmpeg.run('-i', inputName, outputName);

  const outputData = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', outputName);
  const outputBlob = new Blob([outputData.buffer], { type: 'audio/mp3' });

  return outputBlob;
}
```

This function uses the createFFmpeg method to instantiate the FFmpeg.js library, writes the WebM blob to a virtual file system, and runs an FFmpeg command to convert the WebM file to an MP3 file. Finally, it returns the resulting MP3 blob.

Note: this example assumes that you have access to the WebM blob from within your Angular 6 application. If you need to download the WebM file first, you can use the HttpClient service to retrieve it as a blob. Also, don't forget to import the required modules and services, such as HttpClient, in your Angular 6 component or service.

Comment: where is `createFFmpeg` coming from?

Comment: `import { createFFmpeg } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg"`
@Boern

Comment: As of @ffmpeg/ffmpeg 0.12, it's now: 

```js
import { FFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg'

// …
new FFmpeg()
```